# Java WEB project warnings

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish

After starting glassfish server i get this warnings:

```
Warning:   Class 'javax.ejb.PostActivate' not found, interception based on it is not enabled
Warning:   Class 'javax.ejb.PrePassivate' not found, interception based on it is not enabled
```

What can be the reason of this warnings ? How can i get rid of them ?

---

UPD1.

> It appears that NetBeans is putting a bunch of jersey jars into the
>   WEB-INF/lib directory of the application when it is built. These jars
>   should not be placed in WEB-INF/lib

So it might be, because some jars not should be placed in WEB-INF/lib
Here what i have:

[image: libs in WEB-INF]

---

UPD2.

> If you use Netbeans 7.4 and use the "new Java web application" wizard
>   and just click through the defaults except be sure to check the box to
>   include "contexts and dependency injection", then run it on GlassFish
>   4 and you'll get the warning.

### :(

---

UPD3.
[Someone saying here that](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/export/RUN/Glassfish4?format=pdf)
The following warning messages should be ignored, they are 'false-positive' alert messages

---

UPD4. 
Yes, i am using maven. Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>WebSite</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>WebSite</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>      
        <repository>  
            <id>prime-repo</id>  
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>  
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>  
            <layout>default</layout>  
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>    

        <dependency>  
            <groupId>com.octo.captcha</groupId>  
            <artifactId>simplecaptcha</artifactId>  
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>     

        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>  
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>  
            <version>4.0</version>  
        </dependency>  

        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>  
            <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>  
            <version>1.0.10</version>  
        </dependency> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>resources-codemirror</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>  

          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>resources-ckeditor</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>   

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.imgscalr</groupId>
            <artifactId>imgscalr-lib</artifactId>
            <version>4.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.30</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ganyo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gcm-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins> 
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Which Glassfish? Its not like there is only one version.

Comment: @Gimby , GlassFish Server 4.0

Comment: If I google "glassfish 4 javax.ejb.PostActivate' I get this: https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20564 . Does that perhaps help?

Comment: @Gimby , thank you, but there is no solution there :(

Comment: but perhaps there is an understanding of the problem to be found in there (or other hits of the same google search) that will lead you to your own solution. If this were my question, I'd start to add more details about the actual application you're deploying for example and details on how exactly you deploy it. That bug report hints that it is relevant information.

Comment: Are you using maven? Then please add your `pom.xml` to the question.

Comment: @unwichtich, yes, i am using maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason: Classes `javax.ejb.PostActivate` and `javax.ejb.PrePassivate` were not found. You are missing a dependency.

Add this dependency to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ejb-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Regards,
A.